# JQuery calculation after elements are shown

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I'm doing a few simple calculations on. I can't get the calculation to run after I unhide the elements. I have proven that the calculations work outside this form but I'm trying to add it to a form that uses other libraries. I just can't figure out what I need to do to get the calculation to bind to the id's after they are shown. Here's a link to the a partial form with just the needed inputs to keep it simple. [testform](http://ericrohloff.com/test/log/log/test1.html) If you click on "Yes" the elements show that I'm working with. Thanks for any guidance.
Here's the calculation script that I made.

```
<script> 
function pottopot() {

    if ($('#item78_number_1').val()>0 && $('#item76_number_1').val()>0){

        totalpotgals = parseInt($('#item76_number_1').val(),10) 
                       * parseInt($('#item78_number_1').val(),10)
                       / parseInt($('#item47_number_1').val(),10);

        $('#item48_number_1').val(totalpotgals.toFixed(2));

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Open the browser console (F12) and you'll see `"Uncaught ReferenceError: polegals is not defined"`, in other words, you're calling a function that does not exist ?

Comment: Yes, i am too getting "Uncaught reference error strokepolewarn is not defined"

Comment: I cleared those events off. I had left those there because I had already ruled those out as the problem. I removed them but still not calculating.

Comment: Now I'm getting pottopot is not a function. How is that possible. I tried assigning a class to the inputs before but I see the outside libraries are assigning the valid class behind my class. I'm thinking that's where I'm being overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind events after DOM ready. If I understood it correctly you need to put your code in document.ready event. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//put your jquery code here
});
```

As you are already using jQuery use `.keyup` and `.on` to bind events on DOM elements like:

```
$("input.<YOUR_DOM_CLASS>").on("keyup",function(){
//do something here
});
```

Comment: I added that in also but still not getting the calculation. It seems that the forms outside libraries are assigning a class="valid" to the inputs. Not sure yet if that's the problem.

Comment: I added this here. http://ericrohloff.com/test/log/log/test2.html and updated the JQuery lib.

Comment: You have syntax error remove one `}` in your script at end. It will work fine.

Comment: Thanks I missed that going between the two but still no calculation.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help. http://ericrohloff.com/test/log/log/test5.html combination of the keyup and window ready. Thank you very much to all that looked.;)

Comment: @Progrower Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[name=pottopot]").change(function(){
 //call your method that does the calculation.
 pottopot();
 });
});
```

Try to define all your variable. Avoid any console error.
JavaScript will stop executing if there is an error in the page like, variable not defines etc.

To know the error details open the developer tool **CTRL + SHIFT + I** in chrome.